# How to define a map of maps in terraform locals, json syntax

Tags: terraform

Terraform has a [documented](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax-json.html) json configuration syntax.

In the regular terraform syntax, I can define a local map of maps as so

```
locals = {
  my_map_of_maps = {
    map1 = {
      key = "value"
    }
  }
}
```

However in the json syntax, the following equivalent

```
{ 
  "locals": {
    "my_local":"value",
    "my_map_of_maps":{
      "map1": {
        "key":"value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

fails when I run `terraform refresh`, I get `locals block at - should not have label "my_map_of_maps"`

However a map not containing another map is fine

```
{ 
  "locals": {
    "my_local":"value",
    "my_map":{
      "key":"value"}
  }
}
```

passes the `terraform refresh`.

## Not important

An interesting side note, in json syntax, I cannot define a local map unless I first define a local that isn't a map, hence the `"my_local":"value"`. Without it `terraform refresh` fails with `locals block at - should not have label "my_map"`

## Version

Terraform v0.11.13

Comment: This is a known bug in Terraform v0.11, and it looks like you already found the workaround of including an additional non-map value in there to help the parser understand what you meant. Terraform v0.12's new JSON syntax decoder no longer has this problem.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the main issue I raise is also a known bug, do you happen to know a workaround to that one?

Comment: I only see one issue described here: a `locals` block with only a single map expression inside gets misinterpreted as if it were a `locals` block with a label. Could you elaborate on what other bug you're talking about?

Comment: The main part of my question is how does one create a map of maps in terraform json syntax. Tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: The answer is to either use Terraform 0.12 or add the extra property in the `locals` object to work around the known bug in Terraform 0.11.

Comment: Even with the extra property, terraform errors on a map of maps. This question was not about the added property, that is easy to workaround. The question is about map of maps, i.e. depth of 2 in the map.